# How to modify put method to update an array in SpringBoot App

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, microservices, put

I currently have a service that receives three parameters and performs the Update without a problem when receiving data from a front with Angular, the data that I save is from the fields of a modifiable table but it does so only per row, with a single id

This is my method in the controller, with my service and my query

```
     @PutMapping("/{cveEstado}/{comentario}/{idControl}")
    private void actualizaDatos(@PathVariable("cveEstado") String cveEstado, @PathVariable("comentario") String comentario,
            @PathVariable("idControl") String idControl){
        controlService.actualizar(cveEstado, comentario, idControl);
        


 }
```

service and repository

```
    @Override
    public void actualizar(String cveEstado, String comentario, String idControl) {
        
        repository.actualizarCampos(cveEstado, comentario, idControl);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE CONTROL C SET CVEESTADO=?1, COMENTARIO=?2 WHERE C.IDCONTROL=?3", 
            nativeQuery = true)
    void actualizarCampos(String cveEstado, String comentario, String idControl);
```

but now I want to save a whole array, that is, I can update all the fields or some but with different ids

for example

[image]

How should I modify my service and m my query to receive the data like this, someone help me please

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should have a class corresponding to your resource model, this way spring can deserialise it from the request body :

```
@PutMapping("/comments")
private void actualizaDatos(@RequestBody List<Comment> comments){
// you probably should return an http status instead of void
}
```

"Comment" being the java class representation of your json object. spring will deserialise an array of json objects into a list of java objects if the model matches.

```
class Comment {
int idControl;
String cveEstado;
(...)
}
```

note : it is bad practice in REST to update multiple resources at once, any error in one element will be hard to detect as the whole batch will be in error and the client will have no idea why.